# Footer overlaps element:before with position absolute

Tags: html, css, sass

I am try to make a background clip-path behind the element courses and the next element(Footer) overlaps when height is small.
[The problem photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9xbaE.png)

```css
.courses {
    &:before {
        position: absolute;
        content: "";
        width: 100%;
        height: 100vh;
        margin-top: 10vh;
        background-color: cyan;
        filter: invert(95%);
        clip-path: polygon(50% 20%, 100% 0, 100% 100%, 0 100%, 0 0);
    }
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    display: grid;
    grid-area: courses;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(1, 1fr);
    grid-template-rows: repeat(4, 1fr);
    justify-self: center;
}

footer {
    background-color: burlywood;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="main-content">
            <section class="projects"></section>
            <section class="courses">
              <!-- 4divs -->
            </section>
</div>
<footer class="footer"></footer>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use position sticky or fixed for the footer and define the bottom and left properties to place it at the bottom of the fold. Then set a css variable for the height of your footer and use it as calculated measurements added to the elements properties that use 100vh.

```css
:root {
  --footer-height: 50px;
}

* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.courses {
    width: 100%;
    height: calc(100vh - var(--footer-height));
    display: grid;
    grid-area: courses;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(1, 1fr);
    grid-template-rows: repeat(4, 1fr);
    background: lightgreen;
}

.courses:before {
        position: absolute;
        content: "";
        width: 100%;
        height: calc(100vh - var(--footer-height) - 10vh);
        margin-top: 10vh;
        background-color: cyan;
        filter: invert(95%);
        clip-path: polygon(50% 20%, 100% 0, 100% 100%, 0 100%, 0 0);
    }

footer {
    width: 100vw;
    height: var(--footer-height);
    background-color: burlywood;
    z-index: 1;
    position: sticky;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="main-content">
  <section class="projects"></section>
  <section class="courses">
  </section>
</div>
<footer class="footer">1234</footer>
```